# Jquery custom plugin creation patterns

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

What’s the difference between the following when creating jQuery custom plugins?

```
jquery.fn.Myplugin= function(){ /* code */ };
```

AND

```
(function ($){ /* code */ })(jQuery);
```

Is there a specific time you use one or the other.

Comment: The second piece of code you have there isn't a plugin. It's construct to ensure the `$` does not interfere with any other installed frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to create a jQuery plug-in is to first create a wrapper function that lets you use the dollar sign ($).By default, the $ sign can cause conflicts with other JavaScript frameworks. If you wrap your plug-in in a function, conflicts won't occur with other JavaScript frameworks and the use of the $ sign. Other than that there's nothing functionally wrong in the first way.

Recommended way:

```
(function ($){ 
   $.fn.Myplugin= function(){ 
   /* your plugin code here */ 
   };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks it does make sense now